# .xcodeproj opening as code issue on xcode 13.2.1

Tags: xcode, xcodeproj

I'm encountering this weird issue where my .xcodeproj is opening on code. Anyone knows where to check or undo? Currently checking the diff using FileMerge on Sourcetree and so far it's not helping. I'm using Xcode 13.2.1. I want it to open normally like before. Last thing I did before it happened is I just did a `pod install` on my Podfile. Right clicking it via `Open as` doesn't give me any options also aside from `<None>` option.

Answer (score 10):

Did you try to uncheck this? I solved similar issue with this button.

[image: xcode prewview]

Answer (score 0):

What I did that worked was to copy the `UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate` file that was working in my other builds and paste it within the same location in the build that was broken.